# How to put email next to Phone # in header

Tags: html, css

I need help getting an email link to be part of my logo element. I want it to sit to the right of my phone number link. The picture I've included is how I want it to look. BUT, the CSS causes the logo to invert colors when you scroll down. The email link you see in that photo doesn't respond the same way, because I created a 2nd div to contain it out of frustration. But I can't get that 2nd div to behave the same way, I've tried including the same CSS class, etc. When I try to add the email anchor tag in with the logo div, they sit on top of each other.

Long story short, I just want to add the email into the logo div, and have it sit to the right. As it is, it always sits on top of the phone number, on the same line.

[image: Here's a picture of how it should look]

Here's my HTML

```
<!-- Header -->
<header class="header header-fixed header-fixed-on-mobile header-transparent" data-bkg-threshold="100">
    <div class="header-inner">
        <div class="row nav-bar">
            <div class="column width-12 nav-bar-inner">
                <div class="logo">
                    <div>
                        <a href="tel:1-530-680-8255" style="color: grey"><i class="fas fa-phone display:inline-block"></i> 1-530-680-8255</a>   
                        <a href="tel:1-530-680-8255"><i class="fas fa-phone" style="display:inline-block"></i> 1-530-680-8255</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="logoemail">
                    <div>
                        <a href="mailto:#"> <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></i> <strong>lwallaceconstruction@gmail.com</strong> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                                <nav class="navigation nav-block secondary-navigation nav-right">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="aux-navigation hide">
                                            <!-- Aux Navigation -->
                                            <a href="#" class="navigation-show side-nav-show nav-icon">
                                                <span class="icon-menu"></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </nav>
                                <nav class="navigation nav-block primary-navigation nav-center">
                                    <ul>

                                        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home <i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">About <i class="fas fa-at"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Services <i class="fas fa-wrench"></i> </a></li>
                                        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Contact <i class="fas fa-phone"></i> </a></li>


                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- Header End -->
```

Here is the CSS

```
/* Initial Logo Width */
.header .logo{
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 900px;
    top: 0px;
    left: -40px;
    position: absolute;
}

.logoemail {
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 400px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    color: 
}

/* Compacted Header Logo Width */
.header-compact .logo{
    width: 800px;

}

/* Initial Logo Styling */
.header .logo a{
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.header-in .logo a,
.header-out .logo a{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0ms;
    transition-duration: 0ms;
}
.header .logo a:first-child{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.header .logo a + a{
    display: none !important;
}

/* Transparent Header Show Light Logo */
.header-transparent .logo a:first-child{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(5rem);
    transform: translateY(5rem)
}
.header-transparent .logo a + a{
    display: block !important;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

/* Header Background Logo Swap to Dark Logo - On Scroll! */
.header-background .logo a:first-child{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.header-background .logo a + a{
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5rem);
    transform: translateY(-5rem);
}

/* Logo Nav Dark */
.nav-dark .logo a:first-child{
    display: block !important;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.nav-dark .logo a:last-child{
    display: none !important;
}

/* Logo Mobile Header & Breakpoints */
.mobile .header .logo a:first-child{
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px){
    .header .logo-inner{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .header .logo a{
        position: relative;
    }
    .header .logo a:first-child{
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
        transform: translateX(0) !important;
    }
    .header .logo a:last-child{
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cleaning up your markup leads me to think that something was left out. If not, you've got some closing tags in your navbar that don't have opening tags.

Comment: Apart from the comment above (plus some errors with your inline CSS), add `display:inline-block` to the `logo` element, not to a child, and then put the e-mail inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
display: inline-block;
```

So the elements will stay in line.